# How can I transpose these rows into columns in Vue?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to reproduce this table in a way where users can select a number of personality traits:
[image]

I have done this, apart from my columns have turned into rows!
[image]

So you see that on the 1st row of the second image, they should all appear under the heading **Sincerity**, as per the first image - but they do not.  How can I amend this table to look like the first image?

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="header in headers" :key="header" v-text="header"/>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(column, index) in childs" :key="index">
        <td v-for="item in column" :key="item.id">
          <Child
            :selected="selected.indexOf(item.text) > -1"
            :text="item.text"
            @select="selectItem"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Structure of my data:

```
 childs: {
        Sincerity: [
          {
            id: 1,
            text: "Down-to-earth"
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            text: "Honest"
          },
          { ... }
        ],
        Excitement: [
          {
            id: 12,
            text: "Daring"
          },
          {
            id: 13,
            text: "Sprited"
          },
          { ... }
        ],
        Competence: [
          {
            id: 23,
            text: "Reliable"
          },
          {
            id: 24,
            text: "Intelligent"
          },
          { ... }
         ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `display: flex` to achieve this instead of a regular table.

With a table, in each cell (`td`) you'd need to figure out it's header (`th`) above so you know from what list to get the trait.

With flex, you can group the columns properly, and your html can be as simple as

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="category" v-for="header in categoryHeaders" :key="header">
    <h2>{{ header }}</h2>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="child in categoryChildren(header)">
        <span>{{ child.text }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the only css to get these into columns would be

```
#app {
  display: flex;
}
```

I have a more complete [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fLwbc9oq/6/) with how I would initially approach it